# Using signed integers instead of unsigned integers

Tags: swift, unsigned

In software development, it's usually a good idea to take advantage of compiler-errors.  Allowing the compiler to work for you by checking your code makes sense.  In strong-type languages, if a variable only has two valid values, you'd make it a boolean or define an enum for it.  Swift furthers this by bringing the `Optional` type.

In my mind, the same would apply to unsigned integers: if you know a negative value is impossible, program in a way that enforces it.  *I'm talking about high-level APIs; not low-level APIs where the negative value is usually used as a cryptic error signalling mechanism.*

And yet Apple [suggests](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID320) avoiding unsigned integers:

> Use `UInt` only when you specifically need an unsigned integer type with the same size as the platform’s native word size. If this is not the case, `Int` is preferred, even when the values to be stored are known to be non-negative. [...]

Here's an example: Swift's [`Array.count`](http://swiftdoc.org/type/Array/) returns an `Int`.  How can one possibly have negative amount of items?!

#### Why?!

Apple's states that:

> A consistent use of `Int` for integer values aids code interoperability, avoids the need to convert between different number types, and matches integer type inference, as described in [Type Safety and Type Inference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID322).

But I don't buy it!  Using `Int` wouldn't aid "interoperability" anymore than `UInt` since `Int` could resolve to `Int32` or `Int64` (for 32-bit and 64-bit platforms respectively).

---

If you care about robustness at all, using signed integers where it makes no logical sense essentially forces to do an additional check (What if the value is negative?)

I can't see the act of casting between signed and unsigned as being anything other than trivial.  Wouldn't that simply indicate the compiler to resolve the machine-code to use either signed or unsigned byte-codes?!

Comment: Observation: In the recent Xcode 6.3 beta, GCD calls went from using `UInt` to passing `Int`.

Comment: While I'm sympathetic to your point in principle, in practice I've had some very simple routines become very ugly casting back and forth b/w signed and unsigned types. Apple is striving to get this syntactic noise out of our code, which I appreciate. But, this is a very conscious decision on their part, so I'm not sure what you want this audience to make of this question, other than soliciting opinions on the topic. Perhaps this would be better suited for https://devforums.apple.com?

Comment: I already posted on devforums.apple.com (around the same time as I did here). Thank you!  But I was posting here to see if there was a general widely known logical/engineering/mathematical reason I was missing. I was hoping it wasn't zealous oversimplification — which, from what you say, it is — as that would be worst.

Answer (score 0):

1. Casting back and forth between signed and unsigned integers is extremely bug-prone on one side while adds little value on the other.
2. One reason to have unsigned int that you suggest, being an implicit guarantee that an index never gets negative value.. well, it's a bit speculative.  Where would the potential to get a negative value come from?  Of course, from the code, that is, either from a static value or from a computation.  But in both cases, for a static or a computed value *to* *be* *able* to get negative they must be handled as signed integers.  Therefore, it is a language implementation responsibility to introduce all sorts of checks every time you assign signed value to unsigned variable (or vice versa).  This means that we talk not about being forced "to do an additional check" or not, but about having this check implicitly made for us by the language every time we feel lazy to bother with corner cases.
3. Conceptually, signed and unsigned integers come into the language from low level (machine codes).  In other words, unsigned integer is in the language not because it is the language that has a need, but because it is directly bridge-able to machine instructions, hence allows performance gain just for being native.  No other big reason behind.  Therefore, if one has just a glimpse of portability in mind, then one would say "Be it Int and this is it.  Let developer write clean code, we bring the rest".

Answer (score 0):

As long as we have an opinions based question...

Basing programming language mathematical operations on machine register size is one of the great travesties of Computer Science.  There should be Integer*, Rational, Real and Complex - done and dusted.  You need something that maps to a U8 Register for some device driver?  Call it a RegisterOfU8Data - or whatever - just not 'Int(eger)'

*Of course, calling it an 'Integer' means it 'rolls over' to an unlimited range, aka BigNum.

Answer (score 0):

*Sharing what I've discovered which* indirectly *helps me understand... at least in part.  Maybe it ends up helping others?!*

After a few days of digging and thinking, it seems part of my problem boils down to the usage of the word "**casting**".

As far back as I can remember, I've been taught that **casting** was very distinct and different from **converting** in the following ways:

- *Converting* kept the meaning but changed the data.
- *Casting* kept the data but changed the meaning.

Casting was a mechanism allowing you to inform the compiler how both it and you would be manipulating some piece of data (No changing of data, thus no cost). *" **Me to the compiler:** Okay! Initially I told you this byte was an number because I wanted to perform math on it.  Now, lets treat it as an ASCII character."*

Converting was a mechanism for transforming the data into different formats. *" **Me to the compiler:** I have this number, please generate an ASCII string that represents that value."*

---

My problem, it seems, is that in Swift (and most likely other languages) the line between casting and converting is blurred...

Case in point, Apple [explains](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) that:

> Type casting in Swift is implemented with the `is` and `as` operators. […]

```
var x: Int = 5
var y: UInt = x as UInt   // Casting... Compiler refuses claiming 
                          // it's not "convertible".
                          // I don't want to convert it, I want to cast it.
```

If "casting" is not this clearly defined action it could explain **why** unsigned integers are to be avoided like the plague...